# Why does the user.errors.rejectValue printing on the screen at the errors message- after the errorCode also the objectName?

Tags: java

Why does the user.errors.rejectValue printing on the screen at the errors message- after the errorCode also the objectName ?
for example:
if the errorCode is `"error input"` so if prints at the errors message

```
"error input..com.model.security.Person.password"
```

com.model.security.Person.password -> its the name of the error object.

Edit code :

```
user.errors.rejectValue("password", message)
```

Comment: what? where is the code?

Comment: Show us the code, and the stacktrace...

Comment: user.errors.rejectValue("password", message) - how do I put it in a code pattern in my comment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Error message in properties file with mapping to Error message id and define way to read Properties file to application.

Comment: It shows the error messages fine, just it chaining to the end of the error messages the object name.

Comment: I can't do it on the properties file because I need a chaining of a few messages that are created at run time depended on a few conditions

Comment: Do you have another way?